# prove that for $G$ a multiplicative nonabelian group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, any proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I need to prove that for $G$ a multiplicative nonabelian group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, any proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian. I use that, from Lagrange's theorem, the order of the proper subgroups must divide the order of the group and so the subgroups have the orders $p,q$. If $(p,q)=1$, then there exist $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $pk+gl=1$ and so, for an $x$ of a subgroup of order $p$ we obtain $x=x^{lq}$ and similarly, for an $y$ of order $q$ $y=y^{pk}$. Also, $p|lq-1$ and $q|pk-1$. This are the only valuable information I obtained. How can I prove this?

Comment: You need just the first line.

Comment: Try to avoid unnecessary assumptions. You don't need to assume that the group $G$  is multiplicative, and you don't need to assume that it is nonabelian.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: use Lagrange's Theorem, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the whole group. And, a group of prime order must be cyclic (also follows from Lagrange).

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's theorem we can say that order of any proper subgroup of $G$ is either of order $p$ or of order $q.$ Since $p$ and $q$ are primes and we know that any group of prime order is cyclic so any proper subgroup of the group $G$ is cyclic and hence abelian.